# How to return to app from play directive in alexa app?

Tags: php, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am developing an app for audio streming. if i am saying alexa to play song for this artist, alexa is playing all the song. But is not listening in between to switch to another artist. Alexa is completing all the song for the artist and then stopped then i need to launch the app again to listen to another artist's song. How do i call for another artist in between the song?

here is my coding for the first song

```
$speech     = "playing songs of $artistName";

$card = '"card": {
              "type": "Simple",
              "title": "Play Audio",
              "content": ""
        }';
$response = '{
        "version" : "1.0",
        "response" : {
            "outputSpeech": {
              "type": "PlainText",
              "text": "'.$speech.'"
            },
            '.$card.',
            "directives": [
              {
                "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
                "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
                "audioItem": {
                  "stream": {
                "token": "FirstSong",
                "url": "myUrl",
                "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "shouldEndSession" : true
        }
    }';

  echo $response;
```

And then adding the audio to it by replacing playBehaviour to ENQUEUE. Songs are getting added and every song is getting played properly but at any point of time if I am saying any command related to my app.. alexa is not responding and it is actually like getting out of my app because i have to launch the app again once song is playing to make alexa work with my app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the audio player events described [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference).  Specifically, on a AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished event, you can enqueue the next audio file.  Note, many of the other events should also be implemented for a proper user experience.

Comment: it's not about adding the song.. song is getting added but if i want to start asking to do alexa something on my app.. it is not happening because play directive has left the session. Is there anyway to retain the session?

Comment: No, the user needs to retrigger the skill.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now by using the [ASK Music Skill API](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/870491c3-0e95-4ea9-9e2e-ce1ae0cf0a79/now-available-use-the-ask-music-skill-api-to-stream-from-your-music-service-to-alexa-customers) that allows you to create skills that manage your own music library.